# Get correlation along all rows, between two columns DF

Tags: pandas, dataframe

All help is much much appreciated! Thanks

I need correlation along the rows
I know how to get corr between two columns, see below.

How I get the corr along the rows in a new column?
corr (11 with 84
2 with 81) etc

```
df['Bananas'].corr(df['Weight'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Bananas': [11, 2, 0.5], 'Weight': [84, 81, 78]})
```

Comment: What is expected output given this data?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [df.corrwith()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html). This finds correlation row-wise.